# How to empty the input stream in C++?

Tags: c++, iostream

I know how to do this in C but have no idea for a C++ solution. I want the following to be fail safe, but after providing a string or even a char to the input, the program hangs. How to read input stream including \n to free it?

```
int main() {
    int num;
    do { 
        std::cin.clear();
        std::cin >> num;
        while ( std::cin.get() != '\n' );
    } while ( !std::cin.good() || num > 5 );
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Shouldn't you be advancing to the newline *after* clearing the state?

Comment: `std::getline(std::cin, string)`?

Comment: @maverik what string do you mean?

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes I don't see what difference does it make in this case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Once the stream is in an error state all read operations will fail. This means that, if the `cin >> num` read fails, the loop with the `get()` calls will never end: all those `get()`s will fail. Skipping to the end of the line can only be done after clearing the error state.

Answer (score 1):

To build on top of R. Martinho Fernandes answer, here is a possible C++ alternative to your code:

```
std::string num;
std::getline(std::cin, num);

// Arbitrary logic, e.g.: remove non digit characters from num
num.erase(std::remove_if(num.begin(), num.end(),
            std::not1(std::ptr_fun((int(*)(int))std::isdigit))), num.end());

std::stringstream ss(num);
ss >> n;
```

- The [`std::getline`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/getline/) function extracts characters from `cin` and stores to `num`. It also extracts and discards the delimiter at the end of the input (you can specify your own delimiter or `\n` will be used).
- The `string::erase` function removes all characters but digits from the `num` string, using `std::remove_if` with a negative `std::isdigit` predicate.
- The string is then represented as an integer using a `std::stringstream` (a [`boost::lexical_cast`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_52_0/doc/html/boost_lexical_cast.html) would have worked as well)

The logic here implemented by the erase function can be any other logic, but this code is probably much simpler to read than the one included in the question.

Answer (score 0):

I would approach it using getline(cin,num) and then catch any fails using cin.fail(). I usually use cin.fail() with ints but theoretically should work with strings and chars also, for example :

```
    string num;
    getline(cin,num);
    if(cin.fail())
    {
      cin.clear();
      cin.ignore();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

One way would be to check the state after every input and throw an exception if that happens
for example:

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

int main(){

int a;
cout<<"Enter a number: ";
cin>>a;

//If a non number is entered, the stream goes into a fail state
try
{
    if(cin.fail()){
        throw 0;
        cin.clear();
        cin.ignore();
    }
}
catch(int){
    cin.clear();
    cin.ignore();
}
return 0;
}
```

After that you can continue with whatever code you wish

Answer (score 0):

To clear input stream, use cin.sync() .
  no need to use cin.clear() or cin.ignore().